# Swagger error - Unable to render this definition.The provided definition does not specify a valid version field

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle

I deployed my .NET Core application to a Windows server and I have now an issue about opening the Swagger-UI in browser with the public ip-address.

I have no issue when I run Swagger-UI on localhost. However the UI doesn't load when I try to access through server's ip-address.

The error is:

> Unable to render this definition The provided definition does not
> specify a valid version field.
>
> Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported
> version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match  openapi: 3.0.n
> (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

As it can be seen in the beginning of the [Swagger.json file (The one that is running on the server)](http://18.193.85.66/Test/API/swagger/v1/swagger.json), then the OpenAPI version field is set to 3.0.1. What I don't get is then why there's still an issue, when the version is clearly set and fulfilled.

I can even copy-paste the json-file into [Editor Swagger](https://editor.swagger.io/) and see the endpoints through that site.

My code:

```cs
namespace ParkShare
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
           Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContextPool<ParkShareDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration
                .GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:ParkShareDB")).UseLazyLoadingProxies());

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo 
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "ParkShare API",
                    Description = "BackEnd GET/POST/PATCH/DELETE"

                });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme."
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
         {
             {
                   new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                     {
                         Reference = new OpenApiReference
                         {
                             Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                             Id = "Bearer"
                         }
                     },
                     new string[] {}

             }
         });
            });


            services.AddAuthentication(option =>
            {
                option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtToken:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtToken:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtToken:SecretKey"])) //Configuration["JwtToken:SecretKey"]
                };
            });

            //For identity, options changes the default password requirements
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ParkShareDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            //Adding Authentication
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";
            })
            //Adding JWT Bearer
            .AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", JwtBearerOptions =>
            {
                JwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthSettings:Key"))),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
                };
            });

            services.AddScoped<IUserModelingService, UserModeling>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserPasswordService, UserPasswordService>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddScoped<IContactService, ContactService>();
            services.AddTransient<IMailService, SendMailService>();

            // Email configurations 
            var emailConfig = Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfigurationModel>();
            services.AddSingleton(emailConfig);

            services
            .AddCors()
            .AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();


        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) 
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");

            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            // global cors policy
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                );


            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me:
http://18.193.85.66/Test/API/swagger/index.html